# How to preselect facebook friends while sending message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am using : FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder  and I am trying to add friends' ids which i get from facebook sdk.Or how can I preselect names before opening facebook message dialog.

```
private void showFacebookMessageDialog() {
        try {
            FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder =
                    new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/")
            .setName("Message Dialog Tutorial")
            .setCaption("Build great social apps that engage your friends.")
            .setPicture("http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png")
            .setDescription("Allow your users to message links from your app using the Android SDK.")
            .setFriends(Arrays.asList("111","123"));
            ;
            builder.build().present();
        } catch (FacebookException ex) {
            // error handling
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported. The setFriends method only supports tagging a friend (in pictures or status updates), and is not used for preselction. We will update the docs accordingly.